# When downloading content in div using txt file all the lines are displayed side by side javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, tags

When I try to download the content in div as .txt file, all the lines in the div in .txt file are shown side by side instead of line by line.

How can I make them come line by line?

```
  <div id="main">
        <span>Content of #main div goes here</span>
   </div>
  <a href="#" id="downloadLink">Download the inner html of #main</a>

   function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
var link = document.createElement('a');
mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

link.setAttribute('download', filename);
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
link.click(); 

}

var fileName =  'tags.txt'; // You can use the .txt extension if you want


$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
  downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5veosy1L/4/)

Comment: in HTML whitespace is collapsed. if you want multiple spaces you have to add `&nbsp;` and if you want a line break, you need tell that with a `<br>`. Or you inject your text into a `<pre>` node, instead of a div.

Comment: Try something like `var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"\r\n");` ? I know it seems like you're replacing the new lines with new newlines but this seems to work. I will have to look into why this is happening. https://jsfiddle.net/5veosy1L/7/

Comment: @NewToJS its working thanks